# Bind selected date from jqueryui datepicker to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to bind the selected date from the jQueryUI datepicker to the model to be used in the controller, but its returning null. I am able to retrieve the selected value when formcollection is used

ViewModel

```
public class EmpViewModel
 {
    public int EmpId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

}
```

View

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, 
            new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datefield" } })
</div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(EmpViewModel emp)
{
}
```

Tried the method in the below article but couldn't get it working
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4

Script

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(".datefield").datepicker();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: that tutorial is five years old whats your MVC version? Please paste your `EmpViewModel`

Comment: @naveen - MVC 5, included viewmodel

Comment: Show the jquery code you wired up for the datepicker.

Comment: @Jecoms - Included datepicker

Comment: any error in browser console ?

Comment: The code you have shown works fine (assuming the culture on your server accepts dates in the `MM/dd/yyyy` format)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to bind datepicker into viewmodel, but these two are common ones:

First, try declaring an id attribute on `EditorFor` and bind jQuery datepicker to it.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateOfBirth, 
            new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "DateOfBirth", @class = "form-control datefield" } })

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#DateOfBirth").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Second, try `HttpPost` attribute on your controller method if your model passed to controller using form submission, and use `ModelState.IsValid` when necessary.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmpViewModel emp)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

If those solutions still won't work, change `EditorFor` to `TextBoxFor` and check how the submission works using both form collection parameters and model binding scheme.

Additional things to concern with:

1. Ensure your `EditorFor` enclosed inside `<form>` tag, or try `@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))` and place the `EditorFor` inside it.
2. Ensure the date format supplied by datepicker is in correct format recognizable by `System.DateTime`, don't rely on JS format (avoid using toLocaleDateString if any). Use momentjs library if you want to use specific date format.
3. Ensure the jQuery is loaded properly, check your browser console for jQuery's presence after page load (see if `TypeError: jQuery is not defined` message exists).
4. Try setting the plain `DateTime` as nullable `DateTime`: `public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }` and insert some code to check against null value.

Similar problems as further reference:

[MVC 4 DatePicker's selected value not getting set to model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144202/mvc-4-datepickers-selected-value-not-getting-set-to-model)

[Bind Datetime Model value to datepicker and pass them to controller method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20126352/bind-datetime-model-value-to-datepicker-and-pass-them-to-controller-method?rq=1)

Comment: Implementing first point by adding id is binding the incorrect date of 01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM, how do i "Ensure the date format supplied by datepicker is in correct format recognizable by System.DateTime" do this ?

Comment: Try to use `console.log($("#DateOfBirth").val())` or similar way in client side to get the datetime output value given by `EditorFor`. You can check if the console output is suitable as proper `DateTime` format when passed to the model.

Comment: Stephen's solution worked for me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042366/how-to-bind-a-textbox-to-a-datetime-field-but-display-only-its-date-part-in-asp?rq=1